# Prove that $\gcd({n \choose i},{n \choose j})>1,~1<i,j<n$

Tags: combinatorics, elementary-number-theory

Prove that $\gcd({n \choose i},{n \choose j})>1,~0<i,j<n$

My work:
I tried expanding $n \choose i$ and $n \choose j$ to find that there is some number that  divides both and after division the numbers are still integers, but I could not prove that they are integers. Please help.

Comment: @gammatester Thank you for the identification.

Comment: $(i,j) \neq 0,n$. I get what you mean but this is not correct notation.

Comment: Please feel free to edit the question to introduce correct notation.

Comment: As stated this is not true. Set $i=j=n$ to get a counterexample

Comment: @Amr But I said that $(i,j)\ne 0,n$

Comment: @Hawk OK set $n=5,i=4,j=5$

Comment: @user133281 I think the edit you suggested was incorrect. I think you should re-edit it correctly to represent it in the desired form.

Comment: I think you might want to say $1<i,j<n$

Comment: @Amr Here, $j=n$, so that does not apply as well I think.

Comment: @Amr, Yes, I agree with your suggested edit, I will represent it like that.'

Comment: See [Lucas' theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lucas'_theorem#Consequence).

Answer (score 4):

*Hint:* Suppose that their greatest common divisor is $1$. Then the fraction $$\frac{{n\choose j}}{{n\choose i}}$$ is written in lowest terms.

On the other hand, this fraction can also be written as $$\frac{{n-i\choose n-j}}{{j\choose i}}\ldots$$